# Microsoft Access: Getting current record & creating child record before insert

Tags: ms-access, join, triggers

In Access, I'd like to give the user a datasheet form to key in some data. This datasheet merges two tables together, a parent (`Product`) and a child (`Book`). I've linked them up using their `ID`s and they share a 1-to-1 relationship. However, while entering data, as long as I key in any `Book` data, the following error message shows up:

**You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table Product.**

And I am clueless as to what to do, so I thought that giving a administrator-only metadata to the `Product` table would help. When I set it to "Book" and create a new row in `Product`, a data macro will then programatically create a corresponding row with the same `ID` in the `Book` table. Does that sound feasible?

Anyway, I will need to retrieve the `ID` of the current record of the `Book` before insertion, so I wonder how'd I be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the foreign key (=field with which the table is linked to its parent table) of the `Book` table is included in the underlying query.